# How to override user-selected value for HTML color input

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm making a web app to control a set of LEDs but I am having some trouble changing which color is shown in the HTML color input. I need to show the user what the current color of the LEDs is in near real-time as it can change due to other factors.

I can use obj.setAttribute("value", color) to set the color of the input which always works, but the actual color of the input only changes if the user has not selected a color yet. In other words, the color of the input element reflects the "value" attribute only until the user selects a color, after which the color shown is always the user's selected color.

```js
setInterval(setColor, 500);

function setColor() {
  document.getElementById("color")
    .setAttribute("value", '#'+Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16));
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="color" id="color" value="#000000">
</body>

</html>
```

I would like to be able to change the actual color shown on the color input element when I want to. Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you simply introduce a boolean variable, which would say is user has selected the color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
setInterval(setColor, 500);

function setColor() {
  document.getElementById("color").value = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
}
```

Using the .value of the element instead of setting the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```js
setInterval(setColor, 500);

function setColor() {
  document.getElementById("color")
    .value = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="color" id="color" value="#000000">
</body>

</html>
```